# EditText how to make it all screen height?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried to make a simple Memo but I had a problem with the edit text, simply I want it like all the screen height so when I click anywhere on the screen the keyboard must pop up to start writing, but in this case I must click on that line at the very top of the screen to get the keyboard.
[image]

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

So when i tried to make the height to match parent the app becomes with a line at the center, and without solving the previous problem..
[image]

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

please tell me how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you perfect result what you want with the attribute, `android:focusable="true"` it will make edit text focusable so that keyboard will appear and  `android:gravity="top"` will move cursor on top of EditText.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/black"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `android:gravity="top"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a ConstraintLayout. it will work if you make all constraints to match parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.procure.hotelapp.Activities.BookaTableActivity">

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try to change the background of your edittext. When you will change it you will see it will occupy the whole screen

**Update**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="123"
    android:gravity="start"/>
```

Basically the background of edittext by default is using 9 patch drawable that fixes the height of it. When you change the background or just place it to @null - no background you basically remove this obstacle